# Element blue not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: html, css, validation, element

I am almost done with my website but I got one more issue.
My headers have to look like this: http://puu.sh/imtaC/1de833f93b.png
But sadly it gives an error..
*Element blue not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)*

This is my HTML code:

```
<img src="images/icon-small.png" class="small-modal" alt="Small Icon"/> <blue>S</blue>t<blue>3</blue>fan<blue>[</blue>NL<blue>]</blue> - <blue>A</blue>bout
```

This is my CSS code:

```
blue{
    color: #2793cd;
    font-family: "Exo", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using custom tags? Also, why do you need to encase every character/couple of characters in `<blue></blue>`?

Comment: ... Wait. Is that an `img` tag wrapping HTML? Use `<div>` instead.

Comment: Check the picture in the main post. I want that colour effect and I have no clue how to achieve it otherwise..

Comment: Its not an img thing, the St3fan[NL] - About is text

Comment: Ahh... Ok. Try it without custom tags.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using custom tags, just use `span` tags and class them appropriately.

Like so:

HTML

```
<span class="blue">S</span>t<span class="blue">3</span>fan<span class="blue">[</span>NL<span class="blue">]</span> - <span class="blue">A</span>bout
```

CSS

```
.blue{
    color: #2793cd;
    font-family: "Exo", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2p3sdrk3/